# check all checkbox (using CSS3 ::before and ::after) programmatically

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a CSS template and trying to draw a table having the following structure:

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="check">
       <label for="checkbox1"></label>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 17:41</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread even" role="row">
    <td>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox0" value="check">
      <label for="checkbox0"></label>
    </div></td>
    <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 07:57</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the input type checkbox are using a CSS ::before and ::after with the following settings:

```
[type=checkbox]:checked,[type=checkbox]:not(:checked){...
[type=checkbox]+label:before,[type=checkbox]:not(.filled-in)+label:after{...
[type=checkbox]:not(.filled-in)+label:after{...
[type=checkbox]:not(:checked):disabled+label:before{...
[type=checkbox].tabbed:focus+label:after{...
[type=checkbox]:checked+label:before{...
[type=checkbox]:checked:disabled+label:before{...
```

I would like to select all checkbox programmatically in Javascript, any idea how I can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`I would like to select all checkbox programmatically in Javascript`

If you want to make all checkboxes 'checked' ,for that you can use :

```js
let cbox = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
for (var i=0; i<cbox.length; i++) {
    cbox[i].checked = true;
 }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="c1">
<input type="checkbox" class="c2">
<input type="checkbox" class="c3">
```

But, if you want to select the `:before` or `:after` elements with javascript, you CAN't. They are `pseudo-elements` and like their name says, they are not actual elements, they are not considered parts of the DOM so they cannot be 'touched', 'selected', 'manipulated' etc. by javascript or jquery etc.

Comment: ok, by select I meant "checked", so you answered my question, I cannot check (select/unselect) those input types programmatically....

Comment: @tiamat i changed my answer so you can check all the checkboxes. But what do you mean `select/unselect` . When do you want them to be checked and when not. In which event you want to check a checkbox ? give me more details pls

Comment: I just want to add an icon on my interface to select all / unselect all lines of my table, your updated answer is working fine ;-)

Comment: Ok :) . Just put that code inside a `click` function of the selectAll button